# User is undefined but response.data is not

Tags: react-native, mobile

im getting a error in react native, trying to set a user state with a response.data, checkout:

```
export default class  Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    region: null,
      errorMessage:null,
      users: [],
      user: []
  }
```

then in the user Im going to get the current user:

```
currentUser = async() =>{
    try{
      const usu = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@backend:user')) 
      const userID = usu._id

      const response = await api.get(`/auth/` + userID.toString())

      const { user } = response.data
      this.setState({ user })
      console.log({user})
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(userID)
    }catch(response){
        this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error })
        console.log(errorMessage)
    }
       
  
  }
```

As you can see I console.logged some things, including the userID, response.data and the user variable that should be the same as the response.data, here is what I got

the user variable:

```
Object {
  "user": undefined,
}
```

the response.data:

```
Object {
  "project": Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6006ba7bdda76e2ab42a133f",
    "address": "av sao sebastião santarem",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-19T10:54:51.019Z",
    "email": "teste@teste.com",
    "latitude": -2.4229215,
    "longitude": -54.7218379,
    "speciality": " dermatologista",
    "title": "teste",
  },
}
```

the user id:

```
6006ba7bdda76e2ab42a133f
```

Comment: There is no property named `user` in your `response.data` and the `userId` which you printed in your console is from the AsyncStorage which you're fetching in first line of your try condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read my comment on your question and do this instead

```
currentUser = async() =>{
    try{
      const usu = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@backend:user')) 
      const userID = usu._id

      const response = await api.get(`/auth/` + userID.toString())

      const { id } = response.data
      this.setState({ user : id })
      console.log({user : id})
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(userID)
    }catch(response){
        this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error })
        console.log(errorMessage)
    }
  }
```